# JQuery: how to track caught exceptions

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-devtools

I am debugging the site with Chrome Developer Tools. If I check "pause on all exceptions", it pauses a few times when the site is loading and points to jquery.min.js(#line). These are only caught exceptions.

How can I track it back to see which function of my code causes the exception in jquery?

Also, should I really spend some time to track it down, if all my scripts function properly?

Thanks

Update. The problem is that I cannot see any of my functions in the call stack - only jquery calls:

[image]
Perhaps I can safely ignore these since all the exceptions are handled.

Comment: a) try...catch; b) throw new error(); c) call stack; d) break points; e) locals -- everything is important. and in debugging mode you have to avoid minimized libraries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For issues like the one you're dealing with I find the printStackTrace method handy and keep it in my dev toolkit.

http://www.eriwen.com/javascript/js-stack-trace/

In a method where I'm having issues, I'll simply do the following:

```
var trace = printStackTrace();
console.log(trace);
```

I hope this might help you out. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

You can view the call stack in the debugger to see if your code caused the invoked code to throw an exception. Unfortunately, you may see some exceptions that were triggered within code running within a timer. Also, keep in mind that jQuery sometimes does a `try..catch` to detect browser traits, so you really should only be concerned with *unhandled* exceptions.

Comment: Thanks, but there are only jQuery calls in the stack - see the picture above.